# DateTime withTimeAtStartOfDay with timezone

Tags: java, postgresql, jodatime

could somebody help or give me some hint with following problem. I have trouble with creating Timestamp in Java. In my db i have timestamp  stored in UTC time for example `2016-10-20 23:30:00.000000` and my timezone is `Europe/Prague` so time is `+1 Hour`. And if i want to select records from `2016-10-21` i have to select also records from `2016-10-20 23:00:00.000000` if i want to have correct results. I am using Postgresql and JOOQ.

```
public DateTime getDateTimeWithZone() {
    return new DateTime().withZone(MyFormatter.getDateTimeZone());
}
```

This code is in service class Localization service.

Then in controller i create joda time Interval.

```
Interval range = new Interval(localizationService.getDateTimeWithZone().withTimeAtStartOfDay(), localizationService.getDateTimeWithZone().withTimeAtStartOfDay().plusDays(1));
```

This gives me

```
2016-10-21T00:00:00.000+01:00/2016-10-22T00:00:00.000+01:00
```

and then in method for selecting records from db via JOOQ i use this construction

```
Timestamp start = new Timestamp(dtRange.getStartMillis());
Timestamp end = new Timestamp(dtRange.getEndMillis());
```

and result is

```
start = 2016-10-21 00:00:00.0
end = 2016-10-22 00:00:00.0
```

but i need to have `start` and `end` one hour back

Also i tried to modify method `getDateTimeWithZone()` with UTC time

```
public DateTime getDateTimeWithZone() {
return new DateTime().withZone(DateTimeZone.UTC);
}
```

range is the same. I think problem is with `.withTimeAtStartOfDay()` but in this case i need to have `.withTimeAtStartOfDay()` return `2016-10-20 23:00:00.0000`. Is there any way how to do it with joda time or new java.time or write some own implementation od DateTime and override `.withTimeAtStartOfDay()` to return shifted DateTime. I will appreciate any help.

Comment: It seems that [JOOQ does not support](https://blog.jooq.org/tag/timestamp-with-time-zone/) the `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` type out-of-the-box.